# Django- call to is_valid() appears to cause MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, post, request

When trying to upload an image file to a form on one of my Django webpages, I can select the image by clicking 'Choose File' and selecting the file in the Dialog box that is displayed.

However, when I then click the 'Upload' button, to upload the image to the project via the form, I get an error page which says:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/

The 'Traceback' on the error page shows that the error is happening in the view:

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

    # budget_formset = BudgetUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings")

    if drawing_formset.is_valid():
        print 'Saving drawing_formset'
        print "Before", [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
        for drawing_form in drawing_formset:
            if drawing_form.instance.budget:
                print 'Instance', drawing_form.instance.budget
                drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
                drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
                drawing.save()
            print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
    else: print 'Drawing formset not valid.',drawing_formset.errors

    budget_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project, prefix="presentations")

    if budget_formset.is_valid() and budget_formset.has_changed():
        updated_budget_presentations = budget_formset.save()
    elif budget_formset.has_changed(): print 'Budget formset not valid.',budget_formset.errors



    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:concept', args=[project_id]))
```

and the particular line it's complaining about is:

```
if drawing_formset.is_valid():
```

As I understand, this error is usually caused by a call to `request.POST`?

I am calling `request.POST` in the parameter where I define `drawing_formset`:

```
drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings")
```

From what I've seen elsewhere on SO, it seems I should be passing a parameter to `request.POST`, i.e. that line would become:

```
drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST["someParameter"], request.FILES, prefix="drawings")
```

But I'm not sure exactly what I should be passing to the call to `POST` as a parameter...? Is this definitely what I need to do to fix the `MultiValueDictKeyError`? If so, what would I need to be passing as a parameter, or if not, how can I resolve this issue?

**Edit**

The full error message displayed in the browser when I click the 'Upload' button, having attached an image file to the form, is:

> MultiValueDictKeyError at /projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/
>
> "u'drawings-3-id'"
>
> Request Method:   POST
>
> Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/
>
> Django Version:   1.9.1
>
> Exception Type:   MultiValueDictKeyError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> "u'drawings-3-id'"
>
> Exception Location:   /Users/.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in **getitem**, line 85
>
> Python Executable:    /Users/.../.virtualenvs/.../bin/python
>
> Python Version:   2.7.6

and the Traceback shows:

```
/Users/.../Documents/Dev/.../.../projects/views.py in upload_budget_pdfs
if drawing_formset.is_valid(): ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
project 
<Project: Test 1>
drawing_formset 
<django.forms.formsets.DrawingFormFormSet object at 0x113223cd0>
project_id  
u'6215'
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/'>
```

The output displayed in the console when I click the 'Upload' button, and am taken to the webpage displaying the error is:

> Internal Server Error: /projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
> >
> > > response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
> >
> > File "/.../.../Documents/Dev/.../.../.../middleware.py", line 72, in process_view
> >
> > > return permission_required(required_permission)(view_func)(request,*view_args,**view_kwargs)
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
> >
> > > return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
> >
> > File "/.../.../Documents/Dev/.../.../projects/views.py", line 1003, in upload_budget_pdfs
> >
> > > if drawing_formset.is_valid():
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 316, in is_valid
> >
> > > self.errors
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 290, in errors
> >
> > > self.full_clean()
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 338, in full_clean
> >
> > > form = self.forms[i]
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in **get**
> >
> > > res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 144, in forms
> >
> > > for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 587, in _construct_form
> >
> > > pk = self.data[pk_key]
> >
> > File "/.../.../.virtualenvs/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in **getitem**
> >
> > > raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
> >
> > MultiValueDictKeyError: "u'drawings-3-id'"

**Edit**

The original `view` that's displaying the page on which I click the 'Upload' button to try to upload an image to the form is:

```
def concept(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions').get(id=project_id)
    deposit = Deposit.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    end_details = EndDetails.objects.get_or_create(project=project)[0]
    presentation_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(prefix="presentations", instance=project, queryset=presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    context = {
        'project': project,
        'presentations': presentations,
        'presentation_formset': presentation_formset,
        'drawing_formset': drawing_formset,
        'deposit_form': DepositInfoForm(instance=deposit),
        'ended_form': EndDetailsForm(instance=end_details),
        'budget_notes_form': BudgetNotesForm(instance=project.budget_overview),
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/concept.html', context)
```

and the part of the template that's displaying the relevant parts of the page (i.e. the form, buttons, etc) is:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax_2' project.id %}" class="autosave_form formset full-width" action="{% url 'projects:upload_budget_pdfs' project.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="presentations" class="app-wrap center-apps middle">
            {% with get|apps:'Budgets' as costing_app %}
                {% for presentation in presentations %}
                    <div id="presentation-{{presentation.id}}" class="app sm {% if presentation.current_marker %}{{costing_app.color}}{% else %}{{app.color}}{% endif %}">
                        <a href="" class="filler"></a>
                        <a class="show-presentation bottom-right" name="presentation-{{presentation.id}}"><img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/edit-white.png' %}"></a>

                        <ul class="flush">
                            <li class=""><h2 class="p-t-lg">Presentation {{forloop.counter}}</h2></li>
                            <li>{{presentation.presentation_date|date:"d M y"|xor}}</li>
                            <li>{{presentation.details|xor|truncatechars:50}}</li>
                            {% if presentation.current_marker %}<li>({% if project.deposit_received%}Deposit{% else %}Current{% endif %} budget)</li>{% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                {% if forloop.last %}
                {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
                    {# Add a new presentation #}
                <div id="presentation-new" class="app sm {{costing_app.color}} outline">
                    <a id="new_presentation" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:save_new_presentation' project.id %}" class="filler show-presentation" name="presentation-new"></a>
                    <a name="presentation-new"></a>
                    <span class="big-head">+</span>
                    <h2 class="no-m">Add presentation</h2></li>
                </div>
            {% endwith %}
        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            {{presentation_formset.management_form}}
            {{drawing_formset.management_form}}

            <div class="col-9 centered-block p-t-lg">
                <table class="left fixed text-sm slim">
            {# New presentation without budget #}
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>




            {# Edit presentation details #}
                    {% for presentation_form in presentation_formset %}
                        <tbody id="pres{{forloop.counter}}" class="presentation-form" name="presentation-{{presentation_form.instance.id|xor:'new'}}" style="display: none;">


                            {% if not forloop.last and presentation_form.instance.budget_items.count %}
                                <tr class="split-rows">
                                    <td colspan="3">Exc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
                                    <td colspan="3">Inc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                                <tr>
                                    {% for hidden in presentation_form.hidden_fields %}
                                        <td class="hidden">{{ hidden }}</td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                                {% for field in presentation_form.visible_fields %}
                                    <tr class="split-rows">
                                        {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                                            <td colspan="6"><label>{{field.label}}</label></td>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr class="split-rows">

                                        <td colspan="6">
                                            {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                                                {% if field.name == 'presentation_date' %}
                                                    {% with presentation_form.instance.meeting as meeting %}
                                                        {% include "projects/includes/meeting_bit.html" with employee=request.user.employee meeting=meeting UID=presentation_form.instance.id %}
                                                    {% endwith %}
                                                    {# <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>Add to calendar</a> #}
                                                {% else %}
                                                    {{field}}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}

                                {% if presentation_form.instance.id %}

                                    {# PDF uploads #}
                                    {% with drawing_form=drawing_formset|getval:forloop.counter0  %}
                                        {# budget_pdf_form=budget_pdf_formset|getval:forloop.counter0 #}
                                        <tr>
                                            {% if not forloop.last %}
                                                <td colspan="3"><label>Budget PDF package</label></td>
                                            {% endif %}

                                            <td colspan="3"><label>Drawings</label></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            {% if not forloop.last %}
                                                <td colspan="3" class="center">
                                                    {% if presentation_form.instance.pdf_package_dep %}
                                                        <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                                                    {% else %}
                                                    {{presentation_form.pdf_package_dep}}
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </td>       
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {% for d_field in drawing_form.visible_fields %}
                                                {% if drawing_form.instance.pdf %}
                                                    <td colspan="3" class="center">
                                                        <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                                                    </td>       
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <td colspan="3">{{d_field}}</td>
                                                    {% for d_hidden in drawing_form.hidden_fields %}
                                                        <td class="hidden">{{d_hidden}}</td>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
                                                <td colspan="4" class="p-t-md"><input type="submit" value="upload"></td>
                                                <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tr>
                                    {% endwith %}
                                {% endif %}


                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">

                                    <a class="button email_trigger m-t-md" style="width:auto;" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=6&budget={{presentation_form.instance.id}}">Email client meeting report</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td class="p-t-md">
                                    <a {% if forloop.last %}id="refresh_presentations"{% endif %}class="update_presentation button fill">Done</a>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    {% if presentation_form.instance.id and not presentation_form.instance.budget_items.count %}
                                        <a class="button fill" href="{% url 'costing:delete_presentation' presentation_form.instance.id %}">Delete</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax' project.id %}" class="autosave_form full-width">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="col-12 box">
            <div>
                <table class="right fixed m-t-md">
                    <tr>
                        {% for hidden in deposit_form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{hidden}}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for field in deposit_form.visible_fields %}
                            <td class="p-r-md">{{field.label}}</td><td class="p-r-md">{{field}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td><a class="email_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=7">Raise invoice</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 box">
            <div>
                <div class="expand-header"><strong class="m-t-md">Costing notes</strong></div>
                <table class="vertical-table left">
                    {% include "projects/includes/stacked_form.html" with form=budget_notes_form %}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 box">
            <div>
                <div class="expand-header"><strong class="m-t-md">Project rejected by client?</strong></div>
                <table class="vertical-form left">
                    {% include "projects/includes/stacked_form.html" with form=ended_form %}
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

and `DrawingUploadFormset` is defined in forms.py with:

```
class DrawingUploadForm(ValidatedForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Drawing
        fields = ['pdf',]

DrawingUploadFormset = modelformset_factory(Drawing, form=DrawingUploadForm, max_num=12, extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

Comment: That suggested solution is **certainly not** what you should be doing. But you'll need to show the full error message and traceback.

Comment: Ok, cheers. I've added the error message and traceback to my OP.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about how you render this formset in the first place. Where are the view and template that do that? And what is the definition of DrawingUploadFormset?

Comment: I've added the view and template that do this to my OP, along with the definition of `DrawingUploadFormset`.